# How to remove special characters from a string via Powershell command line

Tags: powershell, tidal-scheduler

I'm calling a powershell command-line from within an enterprise scheduler (Tidal), in order to strip out special characters, and eventually get it to a file. I need to strip the special characters before dumping to the file, as the post-process scripting has no tolerance for them.

What I have now looks like this:

```
powershell.exe $content1 = "< JobOutput >"; $content1 = $content1 -replace (['\W'],'') | out-file c:\somefile.txt
```

< JobOutPut > (no spaces inside the < >) is the application variable that dumps data in, it can contain any type of characters.

Error message looks like:

```
+ ...  ; $content1 = $content1 -replace ([\W],) |  ...
+                                         ~
Missing type name after '['.
At line:1 char:2324
+ ...  ; $content1 = $content1 -replace ([\W],) | Out- ...
+                                            ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
```

I've tried variations on that, and it seems something(s) needs to be escaped, but the syntax eludes me. Thanks everyone for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this sorted out. It needs to have a full-context command line, like so:

```
powershell.exe -Command "$content1 = '<JobOutput>' ; $content1 = $content1 -replace 'a','b' -replace 'c','d' ; out-file c:\somefile.txt"
```

That works for most characters, only had issues with replacing double-quotes and backslashes. Everything else was manageable with escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

What are the square brackets for?  When you're using a special character class like `\W`, you don't need square brackets; but even if you use them, they belong inside the string. Otherwise Powershell expects a type expression, though in your case it looks more like you're trying to use some other language's list/array syntax.

This works fine:

```
 $content1 -replace '\W', ''
```

As does this:

```
 $content1 -replace '[\W]', ''
```

Both of them produce the result `JobOutput` from your sample string.

Comment: Indeed. Also worth noting that in lieu of using `''` (the empty string) as the the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator's substitution operand, you can simply _omit_ this operand: `$content1 -replace '\W'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. I did try that variation

```
$content1 = $content1 -replace ('\W')
```

but it resulted in an error:

```
\W : The term '\W' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2320
+ ...  ; $content1 = $content1 -replace (\W) | Out- ...
+                                        ~~
```

It seems to be dropping the ' when executed.

Comment: You keep adding extra punctuation, which computers are notoriously picky about. Just like square brackets, parentheses completely change the meaning. In this case, you're telling PowerShell that you want to _run a command_ named `\W` and _use its output_ as the pattern to replace. 

PowerShell is a _shell_. You aren't calling a function in some other language, but running a command; the arguments are just separated by spaces, no parentheses or commas required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).